# Java "cannot find symbol" errors

Tags: java

I am supposed to write a menu driven program that allows a user to enter an animal and the food they eat into an array, and then search for an animal by name and retrieve their diet. I keep getting these errors and I don't know why.

```
Main.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
        inventory myZoo=new inventory();
        ^
  symbol:   class inventory
  location: class zoo
Main.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
        inventory myZoo=new inventory();
                            ^
  symbol:   class inventory
  location: class zoo
2 errors
```

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class zoo
{
    String[][] animals;

    public zoo() {
        String[][] animals=new String[5][2]; 
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i=0;i<5;i++) {
            System.out.println("\nEnter an animal: ");
            animals[i][0]=input.nextLine();
            for (int j=1;j<2;j++) {
                System.out.println("\nEnter a food the animal eats: ");
                animals[i][j]=input.nextLine();
            }
        }
        input.close(); 
        return;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        inventory myZoo=new inventory();
        String[][] animals=new String[5][2]; 

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int myLoop=1;

        String userResponse="";

        while(myLoop==1) {
            System.out.println("This program will allow you to enter 5 animals into a database along with 1 food they eat.");
            System.out.println("\nAlso, you will be allowed to search for an animal by name and find out what food they eat.");
            System.out.println("\n\n If you would like to enter 5 animals and a food they eat please enter 'A'");
            System.out.println("\nIf you would like to search for an animal please enter the animals name");
            System.out.println("\nIf you would like to exit the program please enter 'Q'\n");
            userResponse=input.nextLine();

            userResponse=userResponse.toUpperCase();
            if(userResponse.equals("Q")){
                myLoop=0;
            }
            if(userResponse.equals("A")){
                myZoo();
            }
            if(userResponse.equals("2")){
                myZoo.findAnimal(userResponse);
            }
        }
    }


    public void findAnimal(String animalName) {
        //setting a return value if no match is found
        String matchResult="The animal "+animalName+" was not found";
        //variable declaration for animal and making uppercase
        String animalToMatch=animalName.toUpperCase();
        //place holder variable for animal
        String arrayAnimal="";
        //place holder for food
        String animalFood="";

        //loop to check all animals in arrayAnimal
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
            arrayAnimal=animals[i][0];
            arrayAnimal=arrayAnimal.toUpperCase();

            if(arrayAnimal.equals(animalToMatch)){
                animalFood=animals[i][1];
                matchResult="The animal "+animalName+" has a diet that consists of "+animalFood;            
            }
        }
        System.out.println(matchResult);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is not able to find Inventory class while you are trying to instantiate it. Make sure if you have that class with the name, yes then import it in you program by using import statement as:

```
import pakageName.className;
```

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by import

Comment: import pakageName.className;        Where would I put that at?

Answer (score 0):

Your program is unable to find class `inventory`. Make sure you are importing the class properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several issues. Lets discuss them first:

#### First

you don't have any class named `inventory`. So it should have been

```
zoo myZoo = new zoo();
//instead of 
inventory myZoo=new inventory();
```

#### Second

> input.close();

You are *not* supposed to close the `System.in`. Wondering how that gets closed? `Scanner.close()` actually closes the underlying stream. See the [docs here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close%28%29). From docs:

> If this scanner has not yet been closed then if its underlying readable also implements the Closeable interface then the **readable's close method will be invoked**. If this scanner is already closed then invoking this method will have no effect.

#### Third

It is a strong [convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) in java world to use capitalized class names. So you should use `Zoo` instead of `zoo`. Not that it will affect your code, but it is a convention, and you should honor the convention of Java when you code in Java, right?

---

Now below is one of many possibilities this could be done.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Zoo {

    private String[][] animals;

    public Zoo() {
        animals = new String[5][2];
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("\nEnter an animal: ");
            animals[i][0] = input.nextLine();
            for (int j = 1; j < 2; j++) {
                System.out.println("\nEnter a food the animal eats: ");
                animals[i][j] = input.nextLine();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("All animals entered!!!");
    }

    public void zooAnimals() {
        System.out.println("Here's all the animals in the zoo...");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(animals[i][0] + " eats " + animals[i][1]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userResponse;
        int myLoop = 1;
        Zoo myZoo = null;

        while (myLoop == 1) {
            System.out.println("This program will allow you to enter 5 animals into a database along with 1 food they eat.");
            System.out.println("Also, you will be allowed to search for an animal by name and find out what food they eat.");
            System.out.println("If you would like to enter 5 animals and a food they eat please enter 'A'");
            System.out.println("Ifyou would like to search for an animal please enter 2");
            System.out.println("If you would like to exit the program please enter 'Q'\n");

            userResponse = input.nextLine();

            userResponse = userResponse.toUpperCase();
            if (userResponse.equals("Q")) {
                myLoop = 0;
            }
            if (userResponse.equals("A")) {
                myZoo = new Zoo();
            }
            if (userResponse.equals("2")) {
                if (myZoo == null) {
                    System.out.println("Enter the animals information first...\n\n");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Enter the animal name to search:");
                    String animalToSearch = input.nextLine();
                    myZoo.findAnimal(animalToSearch);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void findAnimal(String animalName) {
        String matchResult = "The animal " + animalName + " was not found";
        String animalToMatch = animalName.toUpperCase();
        String animalFood;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            if (animals[i][0].toUpperCase().equals(animalToMatch)) {
                animalFood = animals[i][1];
                matchResult = "The animal " + animalName + " has a diet that consists of " + animalFood + "\n\n";
            }
        }
        System.out.println(matchResult);
    }
}
```

**Note**: *Take a closer look at the whole code before you use it. There are some subtle modifications that includes the class name for instance!*

Comment: That seemed to run, but it asked me to enter in information before prompting the menu, also after I entered things in I got this error Exception in thread "main java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found at java.util.Scanner.nextLine<Unkown Source> at zpp.main<zoo.java:48>

Comment: @metzmn211 your file name is still *zoo.java*, but in my code the class name is *Zoo.java* (with capital Z), following the java convention. Mark it as [**accepted**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it helps you.